# How is the amount of decimal places in a float and a double calculated?

Tags: floating-point, double

I'm very new to programming and in university we learned about different types of numbers (integers, short, float, double). Float and double are floating-point numbers. In general, they consist of a sign +/-, a mantissa and an exponent. Each part takes up a certain amount of bits. 
A float can show up to 7 decimal places and double up to 16. 
The formular for that was:

23·log10(2)=23·(log(2)/log(10))≈23·0.3≈7     (decimal places for float)

52·0.3≈16                                    (decimal places for double)

I know that the 23 and 52 are the bits for the mantissa. But where does the logarithm come from? How does this calculate the amount of decimal places?

Comment: You have to be a little bit careful with decimal interpretations for binary formats. For example, `0.009999994` and `0.009999993` both have 7 significant decimal digits, but the resolution of an IEEE 754 binary32 float isn't quite enough to distinguish them: under the usual to-nearest rounding, both would map to the same binary32 float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

23 bits can represent 2<sup>23</sup> values. N decimal digits can represent 10<sup>N</sup> values.

The calculation of the number of decimal digits that can represent the same set of values as 23 bits reduces to solving for N in the equation:

2<sup>23</sup> = 10<sup>N</sup>

log(2<sup>23</sup>) = log(10<sup>N</sup>)

23*log(2) = N*log(10)

N = 23*(log(2)/log(10))

Of course, you can't have fractional bits or decimal digits, so you have to round up or down depending on how the result is going to be used.